# scrollIntoView to apply to IFRAME only

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll

I have an element inside of a page with scollbars, which is brought into view on page load via  JS call to `element.scrollIntoView()` - and this works fine, as expected.

Now, if I place this page into an IFRAME, the call to `element.scrollIntoView()` not only brings element inside of iframe to the top of iframe - if the parent page has scrollbars of its own - it scroll the parent page as well to bring the element in question to the top of parent page as well.

I understand this is probably behavior by design, but is there a way to contain "scrollIntoView" behavior to the IFRAME only, or are there any alternatives to have this behavior (without affecting the parent page).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Figured it out](https://codecorner.galanter.net/2014/01/06/how-to-make-scrollintoview-apply-to-iframe-only/). I can set element's parent's `scrollTop` to element's own `offsetTop`. This will make parent scroll to element's position and effect will be local to IFRAME.

Comment: Nice blog post on subject also, Yuriy.

Comment: @Cameron thanks! I do these posts so if anybody encounter similar problem could find solutions. Linked it from here as well just in case.

Comment: This is really sad. Chrome seems to do the correct thing and only scroll inside the iframe. Firefox (v62 ATM) does not and neither does Safari (11.1.1) which means any iframe has control over the entire page. In other words any random iframe can scroll itself into view against the parent's wishes 

Comment: for those just looking for the code -- `document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.getElementById("xB").offsetTop;`

Comment: Perfect example why the full solution should go on Stackoverflow instead of just linking to it. Unfortunately, the above site does not exist anymore.

Comment: @alpipego unfortunately I had to kill the blog, but the post is still available via Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20140126145113/http://codecorner.galanter.net/2014/01/06/how-to-make-scrollintoview-apply-to-iframe-only/ I will update the reply.

Answer (score 5):

The above solution will indeed work but you wouldn't be able to apply smooth scrolling behaviour. Ran into the same issue and figured you can actually fix by using `scrollTo`, and then you'd be able to add a smooth scrolling.

Assuming `container`, and `element` are respectively the DOM elements for the fixed size container and the element you want to scroll to:

```
container.scrollTo({
    top: element.offsetTop,
    behavior: 'smooth',
  })
```

It's then up to you to choose whether you want to get the given DOM elements using jQuery or references.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, element.scrollIntoView() in an iframe was causing the parent page to scroll on my iPad / Safari

I put the following script in the iframe, around the scrollIntoView to fix:

```
var savTop=parent.document.documentElement.scrollTop;
document.getElementById('elementID').scrollIntoView();
parent.document.documentElement.scrollTop=savTop;
```

Answer (score -2):

How about this:

```
window.parent.scrollTo(0,0);
```