# React scroll to bottom of Element without scrolling iFrame parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that needs to scroll to bottom given specific triggers. [Following the answers in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620694/how-to-scroll-to-bottom-in-react) seemed like a nice and simple solution along these lines (full examples can be found in the question linked):

```js
const scrollToBottom = () => {
  if (messagesEndRef.current) {
    messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }
};
```

However, after embedding the App in an iFrame it turns out that this will also trigger the parent page to scroll, which is bad. I tried different variations of the solution linked in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956663/scrollintoview-to-apply-to-iframe-only), but without success.

Edit: some examples of those failed attempts:

```js
// document.documentElement.scrollTop = messagesEndRef.current.offsetTop;
// messagesEndRef.current.parentNode.scrollTop = messagesEndRef.current.offsetTop;
```

Any pointer to how to achieve the same scrolling behavior but without affecting the iFrame parent page would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, [this answer to another question fixed it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52835382/3104318)

code for future visitors:

```js
messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' })
```

Edit: well, this works nicely with all browsers other than Safari & IE apparently..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

give a div at the bottom of the page in iframe an id, lets say: 'bottom-id'.

And declare a hooks, which gets triggered onClick of a button;

```
const [link,setlink]=useState('some-link')
```

and your iframe must look like this:

`<iframe src={link}/>`

and button:

```
<button onClick={()=>setlink('some-link#bottom-id')}>goto bottom in iframe</button>
```